# azure webjob connect to remote mssql instance. Access Denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, webjob

Hi I want to use a web job to call the following code:

```
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigStore.RemoteConnectionString()))
   {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(xxxxxx, con))
       {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (!reader.HasRows)
           {

           }

           while (reader.Read())
           {

           }
           reader.Close();
       }
   }
```

Im getting the following error

> 018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.FiveSecondTask ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is denied 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout,Boolean allowCreate,Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at WebJob5.Functions.FiveSecondTask(TimerInfo timer)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at lambda_method(Closure ,Functions ,Object[] )
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:25  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information Executed 'Functions.FiveSecondTask' (Failed, Id=beb15926-66b3-4f7e-900a-ebf855feb07b)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.FiveSecondTask ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is denied 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout,Boolean allowCreate,Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at WebJob5.Functions.FiveSecondTask(TimerInfo timer)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at lambda_method(Closure ,Functions ,Object[] )
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information   Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is 'beb15926-66b3-4f7e-900a-ebf855feb07b'
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.FiveSecondTask ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : Access is denied 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout,Boolean allowCreate,Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions,DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection,DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at WebJob5.Functions.FiveSecondTask(TimerInfo timer)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at lambda_method(Closure ,Functions ,Object[] )
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??) 
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    End of inner exception
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)
>   2018-07-12T07:13:26  PID[4540] Information    at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)

How would I make sure that the azure can connect to this remote sql box?

How would I achieve this without compromising security?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an incorrect connection string. Can you debug what the `ConfigStore.RemoteConnectionString()` method returns and that it's a valid connection string?

Comment: looks like the wording for my google search was incorrect Azure refers to remote as on premise connections....found a link https://nishantrana.me/2018/02/19/using-azure-hybrid-connections-to-connect-to-sql-on-prem-database-from-azure-webjob/

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that answers it https://nishantrana.me/2018/02/19/using-azure-hybrid-connections-to-connect-to-sql-on-prem-database-from-azure-webjob/